# Rational map whose Julia set is boundary of a square

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, geometry

Does there exist a rational map whose Julia set is the boundary of a square? If yes how?

Comment: not sure this has to do with `complex-analysis`?

Comment: @gt6989b: [Julia sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julia_set) are a topic in the iteration of analytic functions on the Riemann sphere, so that tag seems appropriate. I am more concerned about the [functional-analysis] tag.

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.